# Can I Treat A Practice Pad As A Tom?

Tags: drums

I have an idea of buying a practice pad with a pedal and hi-hat stand. I was wondering if buying some more pads to treat as other parts of the drum would work? Like I use one pad as a snare and another as a cymbal or toms. The sound would be different obviously but it's just for practice.

Comment: During my first and a half year of drum learning, I played on our living room couch, with some cushions acting as toms and cymbals, along with some empty detergent... drums :-) So, yes, you can use anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely. You can even buy entire kits made of practice pads that are much quieter, cheaper, and more portable than a drum kit. Here’s one example:

[image: DW Practice Kit]

https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/DWCPPADTS5--dw-dwcppadts5-practice-pad-set-with-stand

Notice it has a pad for a kick pedal and a place to clamp the kick pedal, so you can practice all the parts of the kit.

Comment: Thought gear recommendations was off bounds.

Comment: @Tim The question is not asking for a recommendation. I’m not making a recommendation. Can you use a practice pad as a practice tom the same way you’d use one as a practice snare? Yes, here is a picture of a major brand of drum equipment selling a setup of exactly that. It’s evidence that others besides just me say the answer to the question is “yes”.

Comment: @Tim When someone asks me what I recommend for practicing drums, this is not at all what my answer is. So I certainly don’t view or intend this content as any kind of recommendation.

Answer (score -2):

Only problem is that cymbals usually live higher than the drums, so finding stands that would accommodate them might be tricky. By the time enough practice pads have been bought, you might as well get some sort of kit. Then you're on the way to being a proper drummer.